# How to add custom metadata to the files of Onedrive?

Tags: onedrive

I indexed some sample html, pdf, text files into Onedrive.I need to add new properties fileds and values to those files. How can i do this. can anyone please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding custom metadata is not supported in OneDrive. The oneDrive is something like a windows folder in the cloud.

There is an open uservoice regarding this requirement in the oneDrive forum - but no clear answer yet.

[How can we improve the OneDrive Developer Platform?](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913708-onedrive-developer-platform/suggestions/6917850-add-custom-properties-to-files-in-onedrive-person#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

The latest reply from Microsoft about the above requirement:

"We have a preview of custom metadata for OneDrive Personal available now. We’re definitely interested in feedback on the approach and how apps will use it!"

**As per September 2017 - update from Microsoft regarding the custom metadata as below:**

"Custom facets provide a way for you to store your own metadata on items. This can be used to keep track of custom state alongside an item, hold a link to a related item in another system, and various other things. Just like OneDrive's own facets, custom facets follow a schema so that you can be sure the data stays consistent and valid, even when used with multiple apps."

MSDN Source:

[Custom facets (preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/custom-metadata-facets?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: I used microsoft graph api to add new folder and new file to onedrive. But i did not find how to add custom properties to existing files.